# gem install fails on linux behind firewall using proxy

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, rubygems, firewall

I'm trying to install fpm on a linux server behind a firewall.
For this I'm using a proxy server with authentication.

```
gem install --no-document -p http://proxyuser:proxypassword@proxyserver.tld:proxyport fpm
```

This fails with an Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'fpm' (>=0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

The same error occurs when I'm using the proxy with the environment variables http_proxy/https_proxy.

When i'm using curl to download https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz it's working fine.
Either using the environment variables http_proxy https_proxy or using curl -x.

I googled some hours and the only solutions I found was workarounds and no real solution.
E.g. "Try to use gem on a computer with no firewall" etc.

So these are the important points:

1. Operating system: Linux (Suse)
2. There is a firewall There is a proxy with authentication.
3. The dns-resolution is working when using curl
   or wget.
4. I have a user whis is allowed to download executables.
5. I am root on the system.
6. I cannot download the gem files with another
   computer because I am not allowed to upload files from an usb-stick.

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got this done with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/false
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
        sleep 5
    zypper --non-interactive install ruby-devel gcc make
done

GEMS="arr-pm-0.0.10.gem backports-3.17.1.gem cabin-0.6.0.gem childprocess-0.9.0.gem clamp-1.0.0.gem ffi-1.10.0.gem json-1.7.7.gem pleaserun-0.0.29.gem ruby-xz-0.2.3.gem fpm-1.11.0.gem stud-0.0.23.gem dotenv-2.7.6.gem insist-1.0.0.gem mustache-0.99.8.gem io-like-0.3.1.gem"

for package in $GEMS
do
        curl -x http://PROXYNAME:PROXYPORT -U "PROXYUSER:PROXYPASS" https://rubygems.org/downloads/$package -s --output $package
done

gem install -l --no-document fpm
```

The installation is running through without any error, but if I'm trying to run fpm I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- backports/2.0.0/stdlib/ostruct (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fpm-1.11.0/lib/fpm/package.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fpm-1.11.0/lib/fpm.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fpm-1.11.0/bin/fpm:4:in `<main>'
```